# Marshmallow Runtime Permissions in Unit Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm creating an app that needs to access external storage of the device. I'm writing unit tests in a test suite that extends AndroidTestCase, and am experiencing issues when trying to access the files I need.

I think this may be due to the fact that the unit test doesn't have the correct permissions to do so. I've stated the permissions in the application manifest, but do I need to do anything within the test suite to allow external storage access since I'm targeting Android 6? I've seen some related posts, but nothing seems to address this directly.

EDIT:
I found a workaround that worked for me... Since I haven't started UI development of my app, I just added code in the onCreate() method of my launching class and requested permissions. This fixed the problem and I can now run my tests that access external storage, but how can this be avoided in the future? Surely there has to be a proper way to get around this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use UiAutomator framework, that allow you to navigate anywhere on the device and interact with any UI elements.

```
UiObject allowButton = mUiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Allow"));
allowButton.click();
```

Comment: The tests that I'm running are strictly unit tests and have no associated UI